# Reducing space between two pictures in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex

Belows is apart of my code and I want to reduce space between the two pictues and also want to make them larger. Please suggest me.

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
       % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{drww_pre_3.pdf}
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{drbb_pre_4.pdf}
     \caption{Distributions of the kinematic variables used in the analysis after preselection. The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Add a `%` to the end of the first line containing `\includegraphics`.  Otherwise, the end-of-line will introduce a stray space character.

Comment: there is only a word space between the figures, if you are seeing more space check that there is no white space in the pdfs themselves, if you use `\fbox{includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{drbb_pre_4.pdf}}` is the frame tight around the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding a `%` to the end of a line, it will suppress the space that is otherwise introduced.  NOTE: if a line ends with a bare macro, there is not extra space introduced.

This will allow a larger specification of `width`, without triggering a linefeed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
WITHOUT \%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
       % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{Distributions of the kinematic variables used in the analysis after preselection. The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}

WITH \%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
       % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{Distributions of the kinematic variables used in the analysis after preselection. The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space between your figures, add a `%` to the end of the first line of `\includegraphics`. Why this is necessary is explained in detail [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/182889).

To make your figures larger, simply change the `width` to `0.5\linewidth`, which is the maximum before the second figure "jumps" to a new line.

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
       % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{drww_pre_3.pdf}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{drbb_pre_4.pdf}
     \caption{Distributions of the kinematic variables used in the analysis after preselection. The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: For me space is not changing. I copied and past in the my code.

Comment: This I used and felt no change.

\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
WITHOUT \%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{ptbb_pre_1.pdf}
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{ptbb_pre_1.pdf}
     \caption{The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}
WITH \%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{ptbb_pre_1.pdf}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{ptbb_pre_1.pdf}
     \caption{The signal has been scaled by a factor of }
\end{figure}